# What is causing this bad shading on this triangulated mesh?

Tags: mesh, shaders, faces, artifacts

I have this beautiful Lamborghini Urraco model but unfortunately I can't seem to fix this bad shading on this triangulated door mesh, it's very hard to see in Blender but it's quite eye-staggering when exported into a game:
[image]

The mesh with the wireframe:
[image]

I've been trying to reduce Auto Smooth but I can't go any lower before the mesh gets like it is without Auto Smooth. I also tried to apply sharp edges and replacing triangles but it still looks bad unfortunately.

[Here is the .blend file of the mesh if you want to take a look.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UPnpphPbPY5zXnexF9NO0ZPOop30y6BX/view?usp=sharing)

P.S. I would like to keep it triangulated because the game automatically converts quads into triangles.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The topology in your blend file looks pretty good, so it may be an issue in the game engine. Can you disable the environment mapping in the game and see if the bad shading persists?

Comment: Yes I disabled AO and such shadow effects and it still looks wrong, and even after generating the AO for the car chassis I can't reproduce the same shading problem  in Blender so this must be a game problem indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try recalculating normals <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>

Also remove any double vertices *Edit Mode* with  <kbd>M</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* and delete any inside faces.

Comment: I of course did that several times to make sure but unfortunately it still looks the same, even though the shading looks almost perfect in Blender...